# Store value from combobox in file name

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to store the value of 1 or 2 comboboxes in a filename.

When nothing is selected, then the filename to save is `OverzichtTotaal`.

When something is selected in combobox Transaction (`Me.KeuzeTransactie`) (buy, sell...) then the filename to save should be `Overzicht Buy...`

When a year is selected in the second combobox Year (`Me.KeuzeDatum`) then the filename should be `Overzicht 2015`.

And when something is selected in both comboboxes then the name should be `Overzicht 2015 Buy...`

```
Private Sub CmdSave_Click()
    If Me.FilePath = "" Or IsNull(Me.FilePath) Then
        MsgBox "Kies een path!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Right(Me.FilePath, 1) <> "\" Then Me.FilePath = Me.FilePath & "\"

    If Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        Shell ("cmd /c mkdir """ & FilePath & """")
    End If

    pathName = Me.FilePath

    If Me.KeuzeTransActie = "" Then
        fileName = pathName & " " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & "OverzichtTotaal.pdf"
    End If
    If Not IsNull(Me.KeuzeDatum) Then
        fileName = pathName & " " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & "Overzicht" & "Jaar.pdf"
    End If
    If Not IsNull(Me.KeuzeTransActie) Then
        fileName = pathName & " " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & "Overzicht" & "Transactie.pdf"
    End If
    'fileName = pathName & " " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & "Overzicht.pdf" & "Jaar" & "Transactie"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptOverzicht", acFormatPDF, fileName, , , , acExportQualityPrint
    'DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptOverzicht"
```

Comment: You don't mention what error you see, but at least _Shell_ is not needed to create a folder. That can the native _MkDir_ do.

Comment: Educated guess, combobox shows string, but bound column is a number? Then use`ComboBox.Column(1)`for second column of its recordsource.

Comment: Are your 3 `If` tests all mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every module should have `Option Explicit` in header. This will require variable declaration and assist with locating spelling errors. In the VBE set `Tools>Options>Editor>check RequireVariableDeclaration` so new modules will include by default.

Reference comboboxes in concatenation. Note use of `+` character in concatenation. Arithmetic with Null results in Null so using `+` for concatenating combobox with space returns Null when combobox is Null and no extra space will concatenate. Concatenation with `&` will ignore Null (unless all inputs are null) and return the string parts. This assumes comboboxes cannot have empty string.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
_________________________________________________

Private Sub CmdSave_Click()
    Dim fileName As String, booSave As Boolean

    With Me

        If .FilePath & "" = "" Then
            MsgBox "Kies een path!"

        Else

            If Right(.FilePath, 1) <> "\" Then .FilePath = .FilePath & "\"

            If Dir(.FilePath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir .FilePath

            fileName = .FilePath & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " Overzicht" _
                 & Nz(" " + .KeuzeDatum & " " + .KeuzeTransActie.Column(1), "Totaal") & ".pdf"

            booSave = True
            If Dir(filename) <> "" Then
                If MsgBox("File already exists, do you want to overwrite?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then booSave = False
            End If
            If booSave Then DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptOverzicht", acFormatPDF, fileName, , , , acExportQualityPrint

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: In the combobox Keuzenaam I need .column(1) to have aankoop....as mentioned ComputerVersteher.

Other thing is when I only select Keuzedatum (Year).
Then the name should be Overzicht Year, now it stays OverzichtTotaal.
Or also a combination of the two.

Comment: Then check if both controls are Null in the conditional and make adjustment to concatenation and reference combobox column. See edited answer.

Comment: I figured a syntax that eliminates the If Then for the filename construction.

Comment: Can someone help me with a messagebox: when the file already exist then question to overwrite, when it doesn't exist than save the file.

Comment: See revised answer.